# How to update blob column in Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I would like to update content from a column of data type `BLOB` in ORACLE 12C. Can you please give me any query which can perform the above action.

Comment: `update table set field = :BLOB_DATA where...` ?

Comment: [Take a look at this question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1026351?tstart=0) at the Oracle web site. Best of luck.

Comment: I will edit my question.